# Extracting object height from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to extract the height of the drone at the bottom from this image

[image]

as precisely as possible. In this image for example, the drone is 10cm from the ground. Anyone know how to make this happen?

I tried using `cv2.dilate` and `cv2.erode` and `cv2.findContours`, but am not able to make any of these methods work due to the messy background.

Comment: Fix the lighting, fix the background, maybe add a scale of some kind in the image so you've got something to go off of, then you might have a chance and its probably still a difficult case.  Good luck.

Comment: I'll echo comments from @Pete, and add that you may need to work with an "edge image." If you're not familiar with Sobel, Canny, and the like, you should read about those. Contours (blobs) are tricky in poor lighting. **Sometimes** edge-based techniques can help. Try to solve a simpler problem first, though.